# how to make a rotate animation c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a half circle and I want to make it rotate 90 degrees when I click the button, I try to make a double animation but it doesn't work

```
            <Grid Grid.Row="1"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  Width="250"
                  Height="250">
                <Border x:Name="EllipseLeft"
                        Width="125"
                        Height="250"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Ellipse Width="250"
                             Height="250"
                             StrokeThickness="7.5"
                             Stroke="White"/>
                </Border>
            </Grid>
            <Button x:Name="btnRotate"
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="2"
                    Click="Try"/>
```

c#

```
private DoubleAnimation EllipseAnimationLeft = new DoubleAnimation(0, 180, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
private RotateTransform RotateEllipseLeft = new RotateTransform(0, 125, 125);

private void Try(object sender,RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    EllipseLeft.RenderTransform = RotateEllipseLeft;
    EllipseLeft.BeginAnimation(RenderTransformProperty, EllipseAnimationLeft);
}
```

Comment: Without a [mcve] that reproduces the problem, your question is not useful. That said: there is no point in setting a property just before you try to animate that same property, and you can't animate a transform (which is a `Transform` object value) with a double. Maybe you intended to animate the [Angle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.rotatetransform.angleproperty) property of your `RotateTransform` object, rather than the `RenderTransform` property of the ellipse?

Comment: You don't have to animate the RenderTransformProperty, but the RotateTransform.Angle property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Animate the `Angle` property of a RotateTransform which you assign only once to the `RenderTransform` property.

Alternatively to setting absolute values for the RotateTransform's center, you may also set a suitable `RenderTransformOrigin` value:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    EllipseLeft.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform(0, 125, 125);
    // or
    // EllipseLeft.RenderTransformOrigin = new Point(1.0, 0.5);
    // EllipseLeft.RenderTransform = new RotateTransform();
}

private void Try(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation
    {
        By = 90,
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0.5)
    };

    EllipseLeft.RenderTransform.BeginAnimation(
        RotateTransform.AngleProperty, animation);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for editing @Clemens, I didn't know I could animate the RotateTransform.Angle property without a Storyboard.